# Flutter upgrader doesn’t detect appStore version

Tags: flutter, dart, app-store, flutter-upgrade

I want to use the flutter upgrader package.

Is there a configuration element I've forgotten to automatically detect the latest version released?

How can I manage the upgrade in the most efficient way?

The problem is that if I don't set the minAppVersion I don't get an alert even if I build a version older than the one available on the appStore.

````
class Check extends StatelessWidget {
  Check({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        child: UpgradeAlert(
          upgrader: Upgrader(
            canDismissDialog: false,
            showLater: false,
            showIgnore: false,
            minAppVersion: '2.2.2',
            showReleaseNotes: true,
          ),
          child: StreamBuilder<User?>(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // print("data ${snapshot.data?.email}");
                return const Home();
              } else {
                // print("no data");
                return const MyLogin();
              }
            }, // StreamBuilder
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ); // MaterialApp
  }
}```
````